# How to execute CMake custom command without building any target?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file with `add_custom_command` that adds a command to unite all the project source files and generate one output `unit.cc` file. Is there a way to just run this command without building any target that depends on it? Like `cmake -E ...` does. I need to sloc the file and don't wanna wait the long compilation.

I tried to look at the docs but they said, IIUC, that I can run commands only when they depend on some target.

Comment: What build system are you using? There might be a target generated for your command that you can just run

Comment: @AlanBirtles UNIX `make`. How can I run it? The command is just a combination of standard bash utilities with the project sources as arguments.

Comment: Everything in CMake depends on targets, but there are custom targets, so you can create a target that does nothing except execute your command.